# Calcular area bajo la curva de una funcion

Tags: c++, c

tengo un probelma con mi algoritmo. La finalidad del programa es calcular el area bajo la curva de una funcion mediante el metodo de Riemann. El error es en la suma inferior. ya que al momento de estar sacando las areas de los triangulos, lo que yo hice es que multiplique por y, pero al monento de dar el calculo es inexacto. Me podrian ayudar, ya busque por todo goolge y no encuentro algun ejemplo.
Tengo sospechas de que tiene que ser con un if que compare las y. Pero no se me ocurre como. Soy novato. Gracias.

pd: Un ejemplo es: 
Limite inferior: 4.
Limite superior: 10.
Numero de rectangulos: 3.

Respuesta correcta: 76.
Respuesta del programa: 112

Analisis: Me esta dando 36 mas, ya que x = 6 es 36, pero cuando x = 7 es 36. entonces no deberia de sumar esa y. Saludos

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

float limiteMinimo,limiteMaximo; 
int rectangulos;  
float ancho;
float x,y;
float area;

printf("\nEste programa calculara el %crea de la funci%cn: y = -(x-7)^2 +19 \n",160,162);
printf("en los intervalos de 2.68 a 11.32 \n\n");

printf("Ingrese el l%cmite m%cnimo: ",161,161);
scanf("%f",&limiteMinimo);

printf("Ingrese el l%cmite m%cximo: ",161,160);
scanf("%f",&limiteMaximo);


printf("\nIngrese el n%cmero de segmentos (rect%cngulos) enteros: ",163,160);
scanf("%d",&rectangulos);

system("cls");

printf("\n**Suma inferior**\n\n");
printf("Datos: L%cmite m%cnimo: %.2f \n ",161,161,limiteMinimo);
printf("      L%cmite m%cximo: %.2f \n ",161,160,limiteMaximo);
printf("      N%cmero de segmentos: %d \n ",163,rectangulos);

ancho = (limiteMaximo - limiteMinimo)/rectangulos;
printf("\n Ancho: %.2f\n\n",ancho);

for( x=limiteMinimo ; x<=limiteMaximo ; x=x+ancho ){

    y= -((x-7)*(x-7))+19;

    area = area + (ancho*y);

}
printf("\nEl area es: %.2f \n\n",area);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes:

1. Para empezar debes evitar comparaciones con float o double porque puede ocasionar problemas(a veces salga 1 iteración más, y a veces 1 menos). Como sabemos que vamos a sumar el área de un número `rectangulos` de rectángulos lo mejor es hacer el siguiente for:

   ```
   for (int i=0; i<rectangulos; i++){
       //Hacemos las sumas.
   }
   ```
2. Ahora vamos en centrarnos en cómo calcular las áreas. Como bien has dicho, el método de Riemann consiste en dividir la función en rectángulos y calcular sus áreas para conseguir una aproximación. La altura de los rectángulos depende del valor de la función que escojamos, en tu caso has elegido el valor más a la izquierda del rectángulo. Otras formas son coger el máximo de la función dentro del intervalo de ese rectángulo (consiguiendo la denominada suma superior de Riemann) o equivalentemente el mínimo (suma inferior de Riemann). Para más información puedes ver la [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integraci%C3%B3n_de_Riemann#Interpretaci%C3%B3n_geom%C3%A9trica). Por último sumamos las áreas y ya estaría:

   ```
   double f(double x){
       return -((x-7)*(x-7))+19;
   }

   int main(){

       //Cogemos los datos...

       double area= 0;
       double ancho= (limiteMaximo - limiteMinimo)/rectangulos;
       for (int i=0; i<rectangulos; i++){
           area+= ancho*f(limiteMinimo+ancho*i);
       }

       printf("El area es %g",area);

   }
   ```

Cabe recordar que cuantos más rectángulos usemos para dividir el mismo intervalo, conseguiremos una mejor aproximación. ¡OJO! Esto no quiere decir que aumentando en un rectángulo, vayamos a obtener un resultado mejor (éste puede ser igual o incluso peor).

**RECOMENDACION**

Para el cáculo de integrales en computación se utilizan los métodos de aproximación, de los cuáles encontramos el [método del trapecio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regla_del_trapecio), el [método del trapecio compuesto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regla_del_trapecio#Regla_del_trapecio_compuesta), [regla de Simpson](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regla_de_Simpson), [cuadratura de Gauss](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuadratura_de_Gauss)... Cada una con sus ventajas e inconvenientes en cuanto a precisión y complejidad de implementación.

Sin embargo el método del trapecio compuesto es fácil de entender y de implementar, y lo recomiendo antes que el método de Riemann directamente:

El método del trapecio compuesto se caracteriza por dividir el área que hay debajo de la función en trapecios, por lo que lo único que tenemos que saber es calcular el área de un trapecio.

[image: Metodo del trapecio]

Aquí el código de ejemplo:

```
double f(double x){
    double y= -((x-7)*(x-7))+19;
    return y;
}

double metodoTrapecio(double limIzq, double limDer){
    double ancho= limDer-limIzq;
    double area= ancho*(f(limIzq)+f(limDer))/2.0;
    return area;
}

double metodoTrapecioCompuesto(double limIzq, double limDer, int numPuntos){
    double paso= (limDer-limIzq)/numPuntos;
    double area= 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numPuntos-1; i++){
        area+= metodoTrapecio(limIzq+paso*i,limIzq+paso*(i+1));
    }
    return area;
}


int main(){
    printf("El area es %g",metodoTrapecioCompuesto(4,10,4));
    return 0;
}
```

En este código se calcula la aproximación de la integral de la función que has usado en la pregunta, con los mismos limites, y con 4 puntos de división, o lo que es lo mismo, 3 trapecios, obteniendo un resultado de `73,6875`. Date cuenta que he usado el método del trapecio 'simple' para implementar el método del trapecio compuesto. Hay una manera más eficiente que es usando la fórmula que puedes encontrar en [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regla_del_trapecio#Regla_del_trapecio_compuesta):

```
double f(double x){
    double y= -((x-7)*(x-7))+19;
    return y;
}


double metodoTrapecioCompuesto(double limIzq, double limDer, int numPuntos){
    double h= (limDer-limIzq)/numPuntos;
    double area= 0;
    for (int i=1; i<numPuntos-2; i++){
        area+= f(limIzq+ancho*i);
    }
    area+= h/2*(area+f(limIzq)+f(limDer))
    return area;
}


int main(){
    printf("El area es %g",metodoTrapecioCompuesto(4,10,4));
    return 0;
}
```

De esta forma he conseguido el resultado `73.625`.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estas haciendo 1 iteracion extra en tu for loop.  Puedes agregar el ancho al limiteMinimo para evitarlo.  Quedaria asi:

```
limiteMinimo = limiteMinimo + ancho;
for( x=limiteMinimo ; x<=limiteMaximo ; x=x+ancho ){

    y= -((x-7)*(x-7))+19;

    area = area + (ancho*y);

}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero sigue sin dar la respuesta correcta. En este caso si meto los datos de arriba de ejemplo, ahora el resultado es: 92